# Merge Statement for same Table does not insert a new row but updates existing row in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c, sql-merge

I'm trying to do an upsert operation using `MERGE` statement on an Oracle 12 DB table called `CONFIG` whose schema is like below:

```
id | name | value
```

If a row with `name` 'NON_TAXABLE_CODE' exists, update the `value` to '400', else insert a new row into it.

**First Try**

```
MERGE into CONFIG dest USING (SELECT id, name, value from CONFIG where name = 'NON_TAXABLE_CODE') src
    ON (dest.name = src.name)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET dest.value = src.value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, name, value) VALUES (src.id, src.name, src.value )
```

This will update the value if the row exists, but does not insert a new row (if no row exists)

**SecondTry:**

```
MERGE into CONFIG as dest USING VALUES (0, 'NON_TAXABLE_CODE', '400') as src (id, name, value)
    ON dest.name = src.name
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET dest.value = src.value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, name, value) VALUES (src.id, src.name, src.value )


Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02012: missing USING keyword
02012. 00000 -  "missing USING keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

**ThirdTry:**

```
MERGE into CONFIG as dest USING (select 0 as id, 'VERTEX_PRODTYPE_NON_TAXABLE' as name, '400' as value from DUAL) as src
    ON dest.name = src.name
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET dest.value = src.value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, name, value) VALUES (src.id, src.name, src.value )

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02012: missing USING keyword
02012. 00000 -  "missing USING keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Could someone please tell me where am I going wrong here ?
Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the `as` before the table alias.  Oracle doesn't use `as` for table aliases in other contexts.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi, I tried that. For the 2nd one, i get "invalid table name" error and 3rd one, "missing ON keyword" as error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your select inside the src does not return any row if the where clause is not satisfied. Thus, it will neither do an update nor an insert when the condition fails.

To avoid this you can select the values from the dual table.

```
MERGE INTO config dest USING (
     SELECT 100 AS id,
            'NON_TAXABLE_CODE' AS name,
            400 AS value
     FROM dual
)
src ON ( dest.name = src.name )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET dest.value = src.value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
     id,
     name,
     value ) VALUES (
     src.id,
     src.name,
     src.value );
```

This will update the  row when the name matches but inserts the hardcoded values selected from the dual when not matched.

[**DB Fiddle Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4e66fc1fac6305f17d22fe73d2bf57ff)

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. My try#3 is almost identical to your solution. I just needed to remove 'as' before the table aliases and wrap the ON condition within parenthesis. Thanks again.

Comment: @Adhyatmik : uh..yeah I saw it know infact. I just looked at your first try and wrote this. That comment from Gordon would have been enough!